# How to render Android listings with syntax highlighting?

Tags: listings, color, highlighting, syntax, java

I need to include the source code of a bigger Android project in the documentation written with LaTeX. Do you recommend any particular package that is capable of **highlighting Java code** and which also addresses the **specific class types added by the Android framework**?
My Android project has been developed with Eclipse.

Optional:

- It would be also convenient if there is any package that reads the project structure with package names and folders and generates some kind of table of contents from it.
- What is your opinion on the [minted](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/) package that uses [pygments](http://pygments.org) as a syntax highlighter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a job for either the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) or the [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) packages; both are customizable and offer Java as one of the predefined languages.

Using `listings` you can define your own set of rules for syntax highlighting for Android (see Sections **3.2** and **4.18 Language definitions** of the package documentation)); Android is not one of the predefined languages in minted either, so you will also have to define a new language.

Additionally, with each one of the packages you can easily produce a list of your listings using `\lstlistoflistings` (with `listings`) or `\listoflistings` (with `minted`), and you can input your code from external files using `\lstinputlisting` (with `listings`) or `\inputminted` (with `minted`).

Since `minted` uses `Pygments`, it provides far superior syntax highlighting compared to `listings`; on the other hand, `listings` offers automatic breaking of long lines and, as far as I know, this feature is not offered by `minted`.

Comment: Do you know of a LaTeX listings definition for Android similar to this [C# list](http://www.godpatterns.com/2006/01/simple-latex-listings-definition-for-c.html) that has been composed by the community or someone else?

Comment: @JJD no; I don't know of any existing definition for Android; perhaps, if you provide one, you could send it to the `listings` package maintainer so that it could be included in future releases.

Comment: I did not know that someone will integrate such options. I definitely will submit it then. Though, I am pretty sure that somebody else already prepared a list somewhere - I just cannot find it ...

Comment: @JJD I've updated my answer with some information on minted (I hadn't seen your edit to the original question).

Comment: Very nice edit of yours. I appreciate the details about the commands and supported features of the individual packages. Seems like a hard decision, nevertheless.